# how to redirect page on default page using FormsAuthentication?

Tags: asp.net, logout, linkbutton

I am using a small application in VS2005. I created a login panel with using login control provided by visual studio.

I used form authentication for this. Its working fine. Now I want to create logout functionality on a **linkbutton** using form authentication.

How I can implement this functionality?
Please provide valuable response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Log-out link button code should be:

```
//sign out from form authentication

FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

//abandon session

Session.Abandon();

Response.Redirect("logon.aspx");
```

you can find more detail at below link .
[Log-Out using form Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6773/Form-Authentication-Tickets)

Answer (score 0):

These things should be implemented when logging out-

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); //Removes the forms-authentication ticket from the browser.
Session.Clear();               //clear all session values
Session.Abandon();             //Remove session objects

FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(); //redirect the user back to the login page
//OR
Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx"); //whichever page you need.
```

Comment: I want to set default page for FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(). Its redirect to login.aspx but I don't have login.aspx page. How I can set this?

Comment: I created login panel on default page.